# Control Sanyo projector with snmp

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

I'm trying to control Sanyo projectors (PLC-XU106) using snmp. Windows application *PJ Network Manager* uses snmp to get temperatures from projectors and to control its status (power on, outputs etc...).

Now I need to control it with a bash script using snmpget and other tools from [**net-snmp**](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/)

Using `snmpwalk -v 1 -c public 192.168.1.99` to get a subtree of management values, I get these values:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: 1.001 00000 01012
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = INTEGER: 0
SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 = STRING: 
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: 
SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 = STRING: 
SNMPv2-MIB::sysServices.0 = INTEGER: 64
IF-MIB::ifNumber.0 = INTEGER: 1
```

And with `snmpwalk -v 1 -c public 192.168.1.99 SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105` i get this:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.101.0 = INTEGER: 1968
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.102.0 = INTEGER: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.103.101.0 = STRING: "Computer1"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.103.102.0 = STRING: "ANALOG"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.103.103.0 = INTEGER: 2
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.104.101.0 = INTEGER: 32
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.104.102.0 = INTEGER: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.105.101.0 = INTEGER: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.105.102.0 = INTEGER: 4
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.106.101.101.0 = INTEGER: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.106.101.102.0 = INTEGER: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.106.101.103.0 = INTEGER: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.106.102.101.0 = INTEGER: 347
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.106.102.102.0 = INTEGER: 432
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.106.102.103.0 = INTEGER: 308
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.107.101.0 = INTEGER: 3
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.107.102.0 = INTEGER: 1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.107.103.0 = INTEGER: 1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.108.0 = STRING: "XU106"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.109.101.0 = INTEGER: -1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.109.102.0 = INTEGER: 1
End of MIB
```

After some tests I've understood that some of these values are:

#### temperatures

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.106.102.101.0 = INTEGER: 347
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.106.102.102.0 = INTEGER: 432
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.106.102.103.0 = INTEGER: 308
```

#### lamp time.

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.101.0 = INTEGER: 1968
```

### But.. how can I change projector state? Power on/Standby or output? I cannot find a MIB definition.

### Edit:

I can power on/off projector with http request:

```
curl -d "POWER+ON=ON" 192.168.1.99/index.htm
curl -d "POWER+OFF=Standby" 192.168.1.99/index.htm
```

But I guess there's a way to do this with snmp, like

```
snmpset -v 1 -c public 192.168.1.99 SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.17363.101.101.102.101.105.102.0 i 128
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you need to do one of these:

1) find the MIB for the device that defines what each of the OIDs are.  If you have that, you can configure Net-SNMP to display the results such that you get more than a string of numbers and a value and suddenly everything will make sense.  But this looks difficult unless it comes with your network management software, as it doesn't seem to be easily findable online.

2) So option #2 is capture the traffic to the device as you toggle the power with PJ and open the capture in wireshark.  It should show you exactly what OIDs are being SET over SNMP to toggle the power, etc.  Then writing a script to mimic that using `snmpset` is easy.

Comment: Already searched for *solution 1)*, now I'm trying to sniff packets from *PJ Network Manager*. How to use `snmpset` when I have sniffed data?

Comment: Well, once you've sniffed the OIDs that PJ is using to change the status of the device, you can just mimic those using the `snmpset` example you've already posted.  In wireshark, or tcpdump output it'll probably show you fully numeric OIDs.  You can either use those, or use enterprises.17363 and whatever comes after 17363 on the dump output.